# unable to retrieve value inside the ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to manually add values to the response that i got from the REST API and use it inside the View . The problem is i am not able to acess the manually added item inside the ng-repeat . Let me explain with my example . This is my search response which i got from REST API . I added values to the search response like this .

```
 $scope.searchresponse = [{
"items": [{
    "employeeId": "ABC",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "DEF",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "NPK",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "PKN",
    "type": "A",
    "alive": "Yes"
}],
"more": false
}]; 
$scope.searchresponse.action = "Test"
console.log($scope.searchresponse);// I am able to see the test value here
```

This is my HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in searchresponse">
<td class=list align=center ng-switch="details.type">
<span
ng-switch-when="D">SINGLE</span><span
ng-switch-when="E">MULTIPLE</span>
<td> {{$scope.searchresponse.action}}</td> // - Tried this didnt work 
<td> {{searchresponse.action}}</td> // - tried this didnt work . 
</td>
```

How can i get the value test displayed there . I would like that value to use in another switch case or ng-if case

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `$scope.searchresponse` is an array, and you trying to add key-value pair like it was an object. What about changing a structure to

```
$scope.searchresponse = {items: [<your-items-goes-here>], action: "test"}
```

so you can access it with `ng-repeat="item in searchresponse.items"` and you can display you action with `{{searchresponse.action}}`

Comment: I have declared `$scope.searchresponse` inside my Contrtoller, i forgot to add here(now have updated the question). the only problem i am having is accessing the action variable which have been added later to the `searchresponse`

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings inside the ng-repeat need to look at `details` since that will be the local scope with your data. So binding some data would look like:

```
<td> {{details.action}}</td>
```